# Pegar o nome do Usuario de um login no Excel

Tags: excel-vba

Boa tarde. Tenho um login no excel que gera um log dos Usuários. Consigo colocar em uma célula da planilha de trabalho o nome de quem logou, mas quando outro usuário faz o login muda também o nome do Usuário anterior. Preciso que em cada registro mantenha o nome de quem logou ao fazer aquele registro. Como resolver isto ??

Comment: podes postar o código que tens para fazer o registo para ser mais fácil alguém ajudar.

Comment: Acredito que você poderia criar uma aba oculta onde vc insere cada linha de registro! Você verifica qual foi a ultima linha e insere o login do usuario na proxima linha

Answer (score -1):

Olá, isso depende. Pelo que entendi, você registra o login em uma célula, mas deseja que os próximos logins sejam armazenados, por exemplo, nas células abaixo, sem risco de sobreposição do login anterior. Correto?..
Ao armazenar o login em uma célula, por ex.: A1 da planilha 1, o próximo login deverá ser armazenado na A2, e o próximo na A3, assim por diante.
Se cada login já é armazenado em uma variável (recomendo), eu faria o seguinte:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = login
```

Adendo: Se deseja saber a data e hora do login, inclua também essa linha:

```
Sheets(1).Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
```

Esse código te dá autonomia de até 1 milhão de registros e realizei baseado numa variável chamada "login", mas deverá renomeá-la para a variável do seu código, além das referências. Desculpa se não entendi bem, mas isso fez sentido pra você?